# Behringer U-Phoria UMC202HD and SKP Podcast 200

Tags: microphone, audio-interfaces, connector, behringer, sound-installations

I have a SKP Podcast 200 microphone that I plug directly in my laptop (P2 conector) to do some recordings. Recently, to improve the overall quality of my recordings, I bought a Behringer U-Phoria UMC202HD sound interface and a P2-P10 adaptor, as UMC202 only supports P10 or XLR inputs.

When I connect my UMC202HD in my laptop (running Ubuntu 16.04), everything seems fine, my operational system recognize the sound interface with its inputs. But when I plug the SKP microphone (with adaptor) no sound is recorded, don't matter which microphone I choose in my OS (I see two options for UMC202HD in my sound controls here). Even the LED that shows if there is any signal doesn't show anything.

I don't have any other microphone to test if the problem is with UMC202HD or the adaptor. This SPK mic doesn't need phantom power to function, so I didn't put phantom power on in my UMC202HD. I'm starting to think that this mic just don't work with this sound interface (as its a "simpler" microphone).

Anyone can confirm if this set (UMC202HD + SPK Podcast 200 + P2-P10 adaptor) should work fine?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the problem is to do with power to the microphone.

A PC mic input sends a small voltage to anything plugged in (Not sure how large- maybe 5v?) whereas a USB interface usually doesn't.

I have a similar problem with my lapel mics.

The solution is an XLR adaptor that turns 48v phantom power (usually available on the interface, but switchable) into a smaller voltage, or to use an in-line battery pack to send power to the microphone.

Just to confuse matters, SKP says your mic can also run on 48v, so perhaps you need to investigate this in more detail for that mic?